# Animations not working correctly when movieclip is shifted to next keyframe as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

By default I had 2 movieclips on first frame on the main timeline. And an actionscript code for first two movieclips.They are kept on each individual layer. They were working just fine but when I shifted all three keyframes from first to second frame on the maintime line. It doesn't works properly. The reason why I'm shifting them to next keyframe is because I wan't to insert a pre-loader on first frame. Here's the output message I'm getting:

```
 at Flashphotographygallerywebsite10_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()
          at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
          at flash.display::Sprite()
          at flash.display::MovieClip()
          at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
          at flash.display::Sprite()
          at flash.display::MovieClip()
          at Flashphotographygallerywebsite10_fla::envolop_3()
```

Here's the actionscript code:

```
/*Re-sizeable background*/
//set stage for FBF
stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";


//define dynamic aspect ratios
var bg_mainHeight = bg_main.height / bg_main.width;
var bg_mainWidth = bg_main.width / bg_main.height;


//add event listener to the stage
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, sizeListener);


//conditional statement to account for various initial browswer sizes and proportions
function scaleProportional():void {
          if ((stage.stageHeight / stage.stageWidth) < bg_mainHeight) {
                    bg_main.width = stage.stageWidth;
                    bg_main.height = bg_mainHeight * bg_main.width;
          } else {
                    bg_main.height = stage.stageHeight;
                    bg_main.width = bg_mainWidth * bg_main.height;
          };
}


//center bg_mainture on stage
function centerbg_main():void {
          bg_main.x = stage.stageWidth / 1000;
          bg_main.y = stage.stageHeight / 1000;
}


// make listener change bg_mainture size and center bg_mainture on browser resize
function sizeListener(e:Event):void {
          scaleProportional();
          centerbg_main();
}


//run initial locations and size
scaleProportional();
centerbg_main();




/*envelope align to center*/
function resizeHandler(e:Event):void
{
  envelope_mc.x = (envelope_mc.stage.stageWidth / 2) - (envelope_mc.width / 1.15);
  envelope_mc.y = (envelope_mc.stage.stageHeight / 2) - (envelope_mc.height / 1.15);
}

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);

stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));



stop();
```

Comment: Do envelope_mc and bg_main exist on this frame?

Comment: OUTPUT AFTER DEBUGGING MODE SET ON:                                          frame2:59]
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()
 at Flashphotographygallerywebsite10_fla::envolop_3()
There is no error message I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your first frame is empty which means that your 2 movieclips are not defined when you run the program. The easiest way to make you sure that this is the problem is to make them alpha = 0 on the first frame and alpha = 1 on the second frame. If you don't have errors, then this will confirm that these movieclips are not defined on first frame. 
The solution is to deffer the code for the second from when these movieclips really exist. Or make them visible = false on the first frame so that they are always available.